# "Teach" without the second object

Tags: verbs

If a girl wants to ask her piano teacher (she is already being taught by the teacher constantly) to teach her how to play a song by piano, can she say

> I like this song. Can you teach me?

without referring the song like "Can you teach it to me?"

I feel if you omit "it", the different nuance will be added as if she is asking another teacher to start to teach her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an established teacher would understand what she meant without "it to".

But over a long time, piano teachers don't usually "teach songs".

Rather, they teach *playing piano* and *reading music* by working on individual pieces, so she might be more likely to frame the request as "Can we work on this song?" or "Can you help me with this song?".